# How do I stop Highcharts creating a new gridline at the extremities of the chart unless a data point exceeds the min/max gridline?

Tags: highcharts

See attached image.

The major gridlines are set to be 500 apart. However, when data points are close to a 500 increment (in this case the highlighted blue bar is 966 which is close to the 1000 gridline), Highcharts seems to be rendering the next gridline (1500 in my example) which is causing all this wasted space on the chart.

Can I prevent Highcharts from rendering a new gridline at the edges of the chart, unless one of the blue bars actually exceeds the value of the gridline?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the setting I needed was this:

```
yAxis: {
  maxPadding: 0,
  minPadding: 0, // only needed if your chart has negative values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yAxis.tickPositioner` function to add a custom logic to calculate ticks:

```
yAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function() {
        var dataMin = this.dataMin,
            dataMax = this.dataMax,
            interval = 500,
            i = roundData(dataMin),
            max = roundData(dataMax),
            ticks = [];

        function roundData(data) {
            if (data < 0) {
                data = Math.floor(dataMin / interval) * interval
            } else {
                data = Math.ceil(dataMax / interval) * interval
            }
            return data;
        }

        for (; i <= max; i += interval) {
            ticks.push(i);
        }

        return ticks;

    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yaphesw4/

**API Refefence:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Thanks - however, I don't know what the interval will be (highcharts determines that automatically for me). Is there a way to get this to work without hard coding an interval?

Comment: Hi @romiem, Yes, you can use the calculated by Highcharts `tickInterval`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x9028r3j/